# Put a link in a flash[:notice]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby and Rails.

I have a Ruby on Rails project that tracks jobs a server is running.  Right now, when I manually create a new job, it announces:

```
flash[:notice] = "Created job job number #{update.id}."
```

I would like to turn the `#{update.id}` into a link to the job on the job list.

The URL for going to the job is `jobs/list?job=1234` where 1234 is the `update.id` that is displayed in the flash notice.

Is it possible to put a link into a `flash[:notice]` statement?  Or do I need to re-work how this message is being displayed in order to turn it into a link?

Comment: If you've tried all the methods below and it's *still* not working... You need to mark the message as safe (with `html_safe`) when you render it, not when you store the message!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I may be missing something obvious, but you should just be able to do

```
flash[:notice] = %Q[Created job number <a href="/jobs/list?job=#{update.id}">#{update.id}</a>]
```

and then just make sure you're not escaping the content of the flash when you display it in your view.

Comment: You can avoid unsightly backslash escape using `%Q[]` or other equivalent delimiters `()[]{}<>` to denote a string: `%Q[Created job number <a href="/jobs/list?job=#{update.id}">#{update.id}</a>]`

Comment: According to [this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/z52zgDgUmbs) this will not work in rails 4.1.  I haven't been able to get it working either.

Comment: Got it working in Rails 4.1 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538891/flash-message-with-html-safe-from-the-controller-in-rails-4

Answer (score 42):

Don't forget to add `.html_safe` at the end of the notice, if you're using Rails3.
So it would say `flash[:notice] = "Your message".html_safe`

Comment: +1 I'm not using Rails3 for this project, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Sorry to be a kill joy, but this is a comment to a answer, not really a real answer.

Answer (score 39):

**The `@template` instance variable is no longer available in Rails 3**.

Instead you can use this in your controller:

```
flash[:notice] = "Successfully created #{view_context.link_to('product', @product)}.".html_safe
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is great thanks - surely it's better to use link_to instead of typing out the HTML in a string! Also I think you still have to do Kirill's .html_safe at the end.

Comment: @user664833 you still need `.html_safe` at the end in Rails 4, just tried it out.

Comment: Works in Rails 5.0, but you must be `.html_safe`  in the flash notice in the actual view in ADDITION to putting it in the controller.

Answer (score 16):

As nas commented, `link_to` is not available from your controller unless you include the appropriate helper module, but `url_for` is. Therefore I'd do pretty much what Emily said except use `url_for` instead of hardcoding a URL.

e.g. if a job were defined as a resource in your routes:

```
link = "<a href=\"#{url_for(update)}\">#{update.id}</a>"    
flash[:notice] = "Created job number #{link}"
```

Comment: When I do this I get text that says <a href...> instead of a hyperlink.

Comment: @jcollum Am guessing you're using Rails 3.x where HTML is escaped by default so you need to either use the `raw` method e.g. `<%=raw(flash[:notice])%>` in your view or mark the message as `html_safe` as given in [Kirill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5542265/63034).

Comment: yes, I tried putting #{thing.html_safe} but learned that you have to put the html_safe at the end of the whole string, not in the #{} subst.

Comment: @jcollum That's right. If you put a safe string as a substring inside a non-safe string then the resulting string is non-safe (which is what you'd expect). So it is the whole message that must be marked as safe to prevent your HTML being escaped.

Comment: ActionController url_for is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version.

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer didn't work for me. But the answer [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26187798/2695310) worked. I'm using `Rails 4.2.4` by the way. With guidance from the answer I linked, here's how I did it:

#### View

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <div id="flash_<%= name %>"><%= sanitize(msg) %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### Controller

```
flash[:success] = "Blah blah. #{view_context.link_to('Click this link', '/url/here')}"
```

The magic is the `sanitize` method.

I didn't need to use `.html_safe` as well.

Comment: I think this is the relevant answer for Rails 5 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Dorian's answer, here's an internationalized flash with a link in it:

```
flash[:notice] = t('success', go: view_context.link_to(t('product'), @product)).html_safe
```

Where your translation (e.g. a YAML file) might contain:

```
en:
  success: "Successfully created a %{go}"
  product: "product"
it:
  success: "%{go} creato con successo"
  product: "Prodotto"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an alias in your controller to the *link_to* function, or the RailsCast recipe:

```
"Created job job number #{@template.link_to update.id, 
  :controller => 'jobs', :action => 'list', :job => update.id}."
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the Rails [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597) helper:

```
flash[:notice] = "Created job job number #{link_to update.id, :controller => 'jobs', :action => 'list', :job => update.id}."
```

Comment: I dont think link_to is going to work in controller unless you include the helper modules in your controller but then that will be polluting namespace.