# How to insert URL into flash messages?

Tags: url, notifications, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249431/ruby-on-rails-put-a-link-in-a-flashnotice) (1) and [this](http://rubypond.com/blog/useful-flash-messages-in-rails) (2) but I'd like to have a simple method to do that... and that works! Both ( (1) and (2) ) does not works for me.

I want to add a link to the 'root_path'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things: First, construct a flash message with a link in it, as you'd expect:

```
flash[:notice] = "Settings updated! <a href=\"#{root_path}\">Go home</a>."
```

Then, in your view, you'll need to echo it as raw content. This skips Rails 3's automatic escaping of tainted strings, so be sure you never pass user input through this flash:

```
<%=raw flash[:notice] %>
```

Comment: You can also use flash[:notice] = "Settings updated! <a href=\"#{root_path}\">Go home</a>.".html_safe