# Rails 3 showing Twitter Button in success notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

In my Rails 3 web app, I show a success message when someone updates their profile. With this code: `redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Profile updated." }`

What I want to be able to do is show a Twitter button, which is an a href and javascript [see here](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton)

How would I add it to the success flash? I have tried just copying and pasting the code but I then get errors basically saying syntax is wrong...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550295/how-to-insert-url-into-flash-messages/4550525#4550525) worked for me and I now have a twitter button showing with the success flash message! :)

Answer (score 0):

You would do something along the lines of this:

```
redirect_to @user, :success => "Profile updated.", :flash => { :url => "<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>" }
```

And in the layout:

```
- if flash[:success]
  ## Display code, etc...
  - if flash[:url]
    = flash[:url]
```

Or something along those lines

Comment: I modified the code to this `redirect_to @user, :flash => {:success => "Profile updated.", :url => "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/share\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-count=\"vertical\">Tweet</a><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\"></script>" }`  and it shows this:  http://i.qyk.in/381d3d74.png

Comment: I have changed the `"` to `\"` and visa versa but it's still shows the html link as text, not an actual link.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wrap your twitter code in a `raw` method to force it to not escape the html and an `escape_javascript` method to force it to escape the javascript

So try something like this

```
redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => raw(escape_javascript(twitter_code)) }
```