# Add link to a flash notice in Rails ActiveAdmin view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am trying to add a link in a flash message on successful create action of active-admin controller.But the HTML of the link is being escaped and  displayed as plain text on view.

Rails 5.2.1, ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]

eg: If I try to do

```
flash[:success] = "Complete this quick survey. <a href='#{url}'>Click here</a>".html_safe
```

The flash message is displayed as,

```
"Complete this quick survey. <a href='https://www.example.com'>Click here</a>"
```

Expected behaviour: There should be a working link in the flash message

Comment: refer {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249431/put-a-link-in-a-flashnotice}

Comment: I had already tried this, but it didn't work.

Comment: This behaviour worked in previous versions of Rails. At least until Rails 3 .html worked as described in the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way (probably not a good one) to achieve your purpose is to override `activeadmin`'s `:build_flash_messages` method which generates flash messages.

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/14d6e500c777e82111faafe9392d90a6efed7e0b/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb#L86

This is the overridden version (added `.html_safe`). Place this code somewhere in initializers.

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base
  def build_flash_messages
    div class: 'flashes' do
      flash_messages.each do |type, message|
        div message.html_safe, class: "flash flash_#{type}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```